# Android and parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

i made a listview with all the posts in the list.
what i want is when i click the child in the list i want another activity to be opened showing that specific post and the related comments
the question is how to know which item is clicked and how to show that particular post ParseObject in next activity
as they do in messaging app in which you click the message from the listview and subsequent messages are shown in the next activity

i might be very thankful to you if you solve this for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this code:

Please implement your object class with Serializable

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                try
                {
                    Log.v("position",position); // hear is your list item position
                    MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // Class must be implements with Serializable
                    Intent showintent = new Intent(context,<activity class to open>);
                    showcontactintent.putExtra("obj",obj);
                    startActivity(showintent);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: i meant to say that my listView is populated using parseobjects(Posts) and when i click any listitem(specific post) i want that item(post) to be pulled in my new activity
But how can i refrence to that(post) listitem in my new Activity so that i can show all comments for that post in next activity

Comment: set Id to your listView item same as your database row primary key, using position of listitem you can fetch specific row from database

Answer (score 0):

Use: Relational Data

Objects can have relationships with other objects. To model this behavior, any ParseObject can be used as a value in other ParseObjects. Internally, the Parse framework will store the referred-to object in just one place, to maintain consistency.

For example, each Comment in a blogging app might correspond to one Post. To create a new Post with a single Comment, you could write:

```
// Create the post
ParseObject myPost = new ParseObject("Post");
myPost.put("title", "I'm Hungry");
myPost.put("content", "Where should we go for lunch?");

// Create the comment
ParseObject myComment = new ParseObject("Comment");
myComment.put("content", "Let's do Sushirrito.");

// Add a relation between the Post and Comment
myComment.put("parent", myPost);

// This will save both myPost and myComment
myComment.saveInBackground();
```

You can also link objects using just their objectIds like so:

```
// Add a relation between the Post with objectId "1zEcyElZ80" and the comment
myComment.put("parent", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Post", "1zEcyElZ80"));
```

By default, when fetching an object, related ParseObjects are not fetched. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have been fetched like so:

```
fetchedComment.getParseObject("post")
    .fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject post, ParseException e) {
          String title = post.getString("title");
          // Do something with your new title variable
        }
    });
```

You can also model a many-to-many relation using the ParseRelation object. This works similar to List, except that you don't need to download all the ParseObjects in a relation at once. This allows ParseRelation to scale to many more objects than the List approach. For example, a User may have many Posts that they might like. In this case, you can store the set of Posts that a User likes using getRelation. In order to add a post to the list, the code would look something like:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = user.getRelation("likes");
relation.add(post);
user.saveInBackground();
You can remove a post from the ParseRelation with something like:

relation.remove(post);
```

For more read: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-relational-data

^why did I copy all the words here instead of just providing the link? Because parse links are broken sometimes and doesn't direct you to the section you need (instead it just sends you to https://parse.com/docs/android/guide and because the doc is so large, you won't be able to find it.